# Convert specific items in a list of lists from string to double?

Tags: python, string, double, nested-lists

I am very new to Python and this problem hopefully has a simple solution that I have not understood yet. In this problem I am not allowed to use numpy or pandas.

The situation is that I have imported a list of lists from a csv-file with the code below:

```
import csv
my_list=[]
with open("my_file.csv", "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ";")
    
    for rad in csv_reader:
        my_list.append(rad)
```

This results in a list of lists, where each element is a string. What I would like to do is to convert a certain set of the elements in each list to a double to do calculations with. My guess is that I need to loop over each list and float() each single element one by one, since float() does not work on lists. However, I cannot come up with a solution that works.

I have seen the solution

```
[float(i) for i in my_list]
```

for single lists, but do not know how to apply this to a list of lists. Especially since I do not want to convert every item in each list.

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: you can iterate over second list like so `[float(i) for inner_list in my_list for i in inner_list]`

Comment: well in this case `[[float(r) for r in row] for row in my_list]` or the equivalent for-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a nested list comprehension

```
[[float(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in inner_list] for inner_list in my_list]
```